# What difference in meaning is imparted by changing the verb form?

Tags: verbs, tenses, gerund-vs-infinitive

These are both grammatically correct:

> - You’ll go back to reliving your college days.
> - You’ll go back to relive your college days.

The former is rather like "I look forward to *seeing* you...", and "I look forward *to see* you" is incorrect.

Since both the *reliving* sentences are grammatical, does the different verb form give each example a separate meaning? Such a subtle difference in wording probably does give a subtle difference in meaning.

Comment: Sorry for the radical edit, but proofreading is explicitly off-topic. And both your examples are correct, anyway. There does seem to be a subtle difference in meaning, which is definitely on-topic and worth asking about.

Comment: That's okay. Thank's for the edit to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first form is usually used when the person resumed doing something that was interrupted. For example:

> After checking his Twitter feed, he went back to shopping for groceries.

This implies that he was shopping for groceries, he stopped to check his phone, then started shopping again.

The second form usually just means that you went somewhere to do something.

> He went back to the store to shop for groceries.

So applying this to your example, the first one means that you were previously reliving your college days, and you're going to resume doing that, while the second one means that you're going to go back somewhere to start reliving your college days.

Comment: Good to see you @barmer here as well :)